# Getting null value in column "userId_id" of relation "pnrDB_run when sending a POST to django backend

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

Still very new to Django. I'm trying to send a post request to my backend from insomnia right now and I'm getting the error Getting null value when I'm passing in the ID value.

model:

```
class Run(models.Model):
    gameId = models.ForeignKey(Game,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='runs')
    userId = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='game')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    isComplete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    deaths = models.IntegerField()
    badges = models.IntegerField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Here is my seralizer:

```
class RunSerialzer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    gameId = GameSerialzer(
        read_only = True
    )
    userId = UserSerialzer(
        read_only = True  
    )
    class Meta:
        model = Run
        fields=('id','name','isComplete','deaths','badges','userId','gameId')
```

My view:

```
class RunList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Run.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RunSerialzer
```

And my request I'm making:

```
{
    "gameId":1,
    "userId": 1,
    "name":"testrun2",
    "deaths":0,
    "badges": 0,
    "isComplete": false
}
```

and the second one I tried

```
{
    "gameId": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Vintage White",
            "photo": "https://archives.bulbagarden.net/media/upload/thumb/0/08/White_EN_boxart.png/250px-White_EN_boxart.png"
        },
    "userId": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "TestUser"
        },
    "name":"testrun2",
    "isComplete": false,
    "deaths": 0,
    "badges": 0
}
```

I feel like I need to create either a new Serailizer to get the instance I want in my Game model with the pk im passing in the request

Comment: Please add code of ```Run``` model class

Comment: @Amrez added model for Run

Comment: read this, i think it's the field you should use https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield

Answer (score 0):

since you are using **read_only=True** on your serializer for two of your fields you need to pass gameId and userId manually to **save** method of serializer.

in your view(RunList) you should overwrite perform_create method like following:

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    gameId = self.request.data.get('gameId')
    userId = self.request.data.get('userId')
    return serializer.save(gameId=gameId, userId=userId)
```